# Why I get Timeout expired error when I access to database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6 to access database.
On development machine I have SQL SERVER 2014 Express edition.
And when I make some complex queries using EF6 it works fine,I get the desired result.

On production machine I have SQL Server 2012 when move the code from development machine to production and the queries fired I get this error:

> {"Message":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task&amp; task, Boolean asyncWrite,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task&
>   task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)\r\n at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget
>   target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\nClientConnectionId:4a0350b7-e91e-42a4-ae04-ae94e294c26a\r\nError
>   Number:-2,State:0,Class:11"}

Any idea why I get the error above on production machine while it works fine on development?

Comment: what are your timeout settings? have you tried increasing the timeout? have you tried setting it to 0 / unlimited to see if it completes?

Comment: @Tanner, I dont have timeout in my connection strings(in production and not in development  machiens)

Comment: @Michael if you're not setting the timeout there will be a default value, best to set it explicitly. I think the default is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the timeout as shown below.Try that and let us know.

**Important Note :** This is just a temporary solution. You have to analyse your EF query and must improve the performance of it. In other words you need to optimise that query. Hence your development database is having less data, you are not experiencing this. But with a heavy data load (like production) you are experiencing the time out issue.The ***best solution is the optimisation of your EF query***.

**Note :** here time is seconds

```
 public DbContext() : base("Default")
        {
            this.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;
        }
```

Reference: [MSDN: Database.CommandTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.commandtimeout(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

A man who seemingly has a broken finger walks into a doctor's office. *"Doctor"*, he says, *"It hurts when I press here"*. The doctor looks and goes *"Well, if you press less hard, it hurts less, right?"* and sends the man home.

When running into database timeouts, the solution is **NOT** to knee-jerk and simply increase the timeout, that's terrible advice you're getting here.

Analyze and profile your queries, and optimize your database and queries based on the findings from that analysis.

Comment: I have updated the post.Can you change your vote for my post now ?

Comment: Thanks for the `edit` and `changing` your vote :) @CodeCaster +1

Answer (score 0):

Better to set **Timeout=0**, 0 will defined as no limit.

```
this.Database.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

Comment: Because you're suggesting to set an infinite timeout on a database connection, even saying it's better than setting a longer timeout, which is total madness. This opens up your application to a whole lot of new problems.